# How do you generate a call graph from a single Java file?

Tags: java, call-graph

I have a Java file with many methods that call each other and the logic is getting hard to follow. I would like a way to create a visualization of which methods call which. I have researched a bit and think I am looking for a call graph or a control flow graph.

There is a plugin for Android Studio called "Call Graph" that I tried out. It does not catch methods calling each other if they are in the same file.

Is there a tool that can do this?

Comment: https://app.code2flow.com/ .... is very limited in the free version
For IntelliJ, there is a plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12304-call-graph
Maybe you can use this.

Comment: The call graph plugin does not catch methods calling each other if they are in the same file.